# Getting error while converting json file to a data frame using jsonlite

Tags: json, r, dataframe, twitter, jsonlite

I am using the tweetscores package of R to get 'tweets list from twitter. The tweets are stored in json format. While converting it to a data frame I get a lexical error 
' Error: lexical error: inside a string, '\' occurs before a character which it may not.".

Any solution to the mentioned error.

A part of the json file text

> ":[{"text":["MUFC"],"indices":[[83],[88]]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[]},"metadata":{"iso_language_code":["en"],"result_type":["recent"]},"source":["http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>"],"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":[7.32108114527322e+017],"id_str":["732108114527322112"],"name":["wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww(^o^)/"],"screen_name":["SukiSukinal"],"location":["+6222"],"description":["Alliansi osaosi ngevote kagak. katanya sih fans a.k.a + "],"url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":[false],"followers_count":[163],"friends_count":[107],"listed_count":[4],"created_at":["Mon May 16 07:19:11 +0000

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide a reproducible example of your data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, I am using the following code to convert the json file into a data frame        tweet_file <- "tweetlist.json"
con <- file(tweet_file,"r")
input <- readLines(con, -3L)
close(con)


tweetdata <- ldply(lapply(input, function (x) t(unlist(fromJSON(x, flatten = TRUE)))))

Comment: iPhone<\/a>"],"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":[7.32108114527322e+017],"id_str":["732108114527322112"],"name":["wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww\(^o^)/"],"screen_name":["SukiSukinal"],"location":["+6222"],"description":["Alliansi osaosi ngevote kagak. katanya sih fans <U+9808><U+85E4><U+51DC><U+3005><U+82B1>a.k.a<U+308A><U+308A><U+307D><U+3093> + <U+5C71><U+672C><U+5F69>

Comment: Don't use the comments section to add details to your question. Edit your question (by pressing 'edit') with the extra details and code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Json format does not allow backslashes so you need to escape them. replace any '\' character found with '\\'. Refer [here][1]

[1]: http://www.json.org/ for more info

Comment: I agree 'backslashes' are not allowed, i tried replacing them using 'gsub' but it is not working

Comment: "Tried with gsub" is ambiguous. How? Remember that regex patterns sent to any rgex need to have any backslash "escaped". This replaces a single backslash with an "a": `gsub("\\\\", "a", "\\")
[1] "a"`

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an incomplete json string, which may be caused by the package or by an interrupted connection to Twitter's API. A complete json string returned from Twitter should look something like the following:

[image: complete Twitter json document]

which I got using [rtweet's](http://rtweet.info) `stream_tweets()` function. With a complete string returned by Twitter's REST or stream API, you should be able to convert the data using basically any json parser (e.g., `jsonlite::fromJSON()`).